# Pandas way of getting intersection between two rows in a python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Say I have some data that looks like below. I want to get the count of ids that have two tags at the same time.

```
tag id
a A
b B
a B
b A
c A
```

What I desire the result:

```
tag1 tag2 count
a b 2
a c 1
b c 1
```

In plain python I could write pseudocode:

```
d = defaultdict(set)
d[tag].add(id)
for tag1, tag2 in itertools.combinations(d.keys(), 2):
    print tag1, tag2, len(d[tag1] & d[tag2])
```

Not the most efficient way but it should work. Now I already have the data stored in Pandas dataframe. Is there a more pandas-way to achieve the same result?

Comment: could you please post a desired output / data set, because it's not clear what do you want to achieve and your code isn't working?

Comment: How does this line work exactly? `d[tag].append(id)`? Sets don't have append methods?

Comment: @MaxU Hi, updated question. Is that clear enough :)

Comment: @ayhan My mistake. Late at midnight here, sleepy and careless. Should be `add`

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt:

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

In [123]: df
Out[123]:
  tag id
0   a  A
1   b  B
2   a  B
3   b  A
4   c  A

In [124]: a = np.asarray(list(combinations(df.tag, 2)))

In [125]: a
Out[125]:
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['a', 'c'],
       ['b', 'a'],
       ['b', 'b'],
       ['b', 'c'],
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['a', 'c'],
       ['b', 'c']],
      dtype='<U1')

In [126]: a = a[a[:,0] != a[:,1]]

In [127]: a
Out[127]:
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['a', 'c'],
       ['b', 'a'],
       ['b', 'c'],
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['a', 'c'],
       ['b', 'c']],
      dtype='<U1')

In [129]: np.ndarray.sort(a)

In [130]: pd.DataFrame(a).groupby([0,1]).size()
Out[130]:
0  1
a  b    4
   c    2
b  c    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: HI just the last step, the value should be half of it?

Comment: @dofine, yeah, i see it now. This still has to be done. I've added `numpy` tag to your question, which might attract NumPy gurus. I don't think there is a pretty, clear, pure Pandas solution for this task...

Comment: It has to involve some kind of combinations, so at least the idea is good here.

Comment: @Divakar, yeah, it seems to be too much for my current NumPy knowledge... It would be really great if you would add your solution (as an extra answer), so we could learn something new from you again ;)

Comment: Thing with combinations is that because of its very nature things just "explode" and they don't stay "regular" as in n-dimensional, where n could be fixed. So, in most of those cases, my vectorized ways don't work. So, I am outta here, sorry though ;)